# Matlab Symbolic Algebra not fully evaluated

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

In Matlab when I do

```
syms x d
laplace(heaviside(x)-heaviside(x-4))
```

I get

```
1/s - exp(-4*s)/s
```

But if I do

```
laplace(heaviside(x)-heaviside(x-d))
```

I get

```
1/s - laplace(heaviside(x - d), x, s)
```

Is there a way to force the last laplace to evaluate?

Comment: The MATLAB documentation says that "If `laplace` cannot find an explicit representation of the transform, it returns an unevaluated call". I'm assuming at this point in time, evaluating your expression further isn't supported. `ilapace` still returns the original function correctly, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often if you want answers out of general symbolic expressions you need to apply [`assumptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumptions-1.html). Using [`assume`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assume.html?refresh=true) to specify that your parameter `d` is non-negative (a delayed step):

```
syms x d
assume(d>=0);
laplace(heaviside(x)-heaviside(x-d))
```

returns

```
ans =

1/s - exp(-d*s)/s
```

For arbitrary real values of `d` the result of your Laplace transform is a piecewise function (if you `assume` that `d` is negative then you'll obtain a different solution). It looks like the [`laplace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/laplace.html) function has not been designed to handle these cases via MuPAD's [`piecewise`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/piecewise.html) (except to return the original call). You might [file a request for enhancement](http://www.mathworks.com/company/aboutus/contact_us) with The MathWorks to enquire about adding this functionality.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't considered that the result what piecewise depending on the value of `d`.